# Problems with auth dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, authentication

I am somewhat new to using the facebook c# sdk.  I'm trying to add the ability to add login capabilities to my website using facebook.  However, I don't seem to be able to achieve the same login auth dialog look that other sites give.

When I view other sites that allow login via facebook (i.e. Bing, Pinterest), their auth dialog screens look exactly like what I am looking for.  That is logo, followed by title.  Then description, then the "By proceeding you are agreeing to...." line.  Then below in the darker gray shaded area is the friends strip, and the Log In and Cancel Buttons on the lower right hand side.  For my site, I am getting an auth dialog with an "Okay, go to app" button in the upper right hand corner of the auth window. It does not show the strip of friends that use the app. and there is no "Login" and "Cancel" button at the bottom.

How can I achieve the desired look?  I have tried disabling the Enhanced Auth Dialog in the advanced settings of my app, but this generates an auth dialog that is even further from the desired result.

I have compared the url strings that I am using to do the auth, with these other sites and they are exactly the same (obviously using my own appid, and permission requested).  So that tells me it must be something on the app setup side on facebook.  I just can't seem to determine what options need to be set to cause my app to display a login screen similar to the other sites I have mentioned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't opted in to the "Enhanced Auth Dialog"? Go to:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/advanced

And make sure "Enhanced Auth Dialog" is set to active.